# Upload file to server that is open

Tags: c#, upload, webclient

So I'm using WebClient to upload a file to a server. It works great except for one problem. If the file is opened by another program then it will not upload. For instance, if it's a word document that's been saved but is still opened by word then it fails to upload. Is there a way to force it to read whatever is there and upload it?

Comment: Sounds like [how do you read a file which is in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709104/how-do-you-read-a-file-which-is-in-use)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right then you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247326/4612655) solution to test if the file is open and then close it if it is. It's a useful helper class i've used in the past.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247326/4612655